# syntax trees from sentences

Tags: syntax, syntax-trees

I really do not understand how to create syntax trees. I am having a very hard time and I cannot figure out how to make trees for these three sentences.

i) The
cat
with
the
long
tail
and
the
dog
without
a
tail
walked
across
the
bridge.
ii) John
explored
the
cave
with
a
flashlight.
iii) John
explored
the
cave
with
a
narrow
entrance.

Comment: Try http://eztreesee.coli.uni-saarland.de/

Answer (score 2):

Syntacticians generally develop an idea about the tree structure of an expression by using tests.  For your examples, one thing to investigate is which sequences of words could be replaced by definite pronouns (he/she/it/they/...) in a context which would supply interpretations for the pronouns.  Those are NPs.  For your example i), I get "They walked across it", which gives a first approximation of a tree:

> [S [NP the cat with the long tail and the dog without a tail ] walked across [NP the bridge ] ]